# Unity OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit functions not visible in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I'm facing an issue in my Unity project where the `OnPointerEnter` and `OnPointerExit` functions defined in my script are not visible in the Unity Editor. These functions are supposed to handle pointer enter and exit events for UI elements, but for some reason, they are not showing up in the Unity Editor's inspector window.

Despite implementing the `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler interfaces` and defining the corresponding functions, they are not appearing in the Unity Editor. I've tried reimporting assets, restarting Unity, and even creating a new script file, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you sure you added your component? cos theres no script listed..

Comment: @BugFinder `UI_Controller`? OP can you still show your code please?

Answer (score 0):

To show those functions in the Editor you need to make sure those two functions are public and can be acessed by the editor: `public void OnPointerEnter()` and `public void OnPointerExit()`. If the error still occurs please provide the relevant code snippets.